# required-deployment-contexts not working for Liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2, liferay-service-builder

I have read that specifying a required-deployment-contexts entry in my 
liferay-plugin-package.properties file would do an automatical service-jar copy process into my portlets WEB-INF/lib.

I can´t get this to work:

I have Portlet A and Portlet B.

**I want Portlet B to consume the service of Portlet A without having to copy the service JAR to my servers ext/lib directory.** I read that specifying the required-deployment-contexts like this would help me :

```
required-deployment-contexts=A-portlet
```

Well at least for me it doesn´t work. The service - JAR file is not copied and thus my B-Portlet can´t use my A-Portlet.

I am using Liferay 6.2 CE GA4
Any suggestions from anyone ?

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/sharing-liferay-service-layer-between-two-plugin-portlet-contexts

Comment: The deployment sequence also matter. You need to deploy A-portlet first, then the second portlet that is using A-portlet jar.

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6018931

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I have already read all those blog entries but they are not helping. Required-Deployment-Contexts works because Portlet B waits until Portlet A is deployed. But the service.jar is not copied ...

Comment: portlet A service.jar?

Comment: As I wrote : "I want Portlet B to consume the service of Portlet A without having to copy the service JAR to my servers ext/lib directory." This is something that required-deployment-contexts should do by copying it into the WEB-INF/lib Folder of Portlet B. That´s not happening, which is the cause of my question here :)

Comment: I think it's related to the build managment tool used (Ant vs Maven vs other).
Useful post: https://web.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/63538639

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if your jar service is called "A-portlet-service.jar".

Indeed Liferay copy jar only if the name is "required-deployment-contexts-value"-service.jar

You can check PluginsEnvironmentBuilder class for the code:

```
protected List<String> getRequiredDeploymentContextsJars(
        File libDir, Properties properties)
    throws Exception {

    List<String> jars = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] requiredDeploymentContexts = StringUtil.split(
        properties.getProperty("required-deployment-contexts"));

    for (String requiredDeploymentContext : requiredDeploymentContexts) {
        if (_fileUtil.exists(
                libDir.getCanonicalPath() + "/" +
                    requiredDeploymentContext + "-service.jar")) {

            jars.add(requiredDeploymentContext + "-service.jar");
        }
    }

    return jars;
}
```